# How to get lastmodifiedby field on history of custom object

Tags: history-tracking

Can we get `lastmodifiedby` history of any field for which custom field tracking is enabled?

Through history like `SELECT ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedById, CreatedDate,lastModifiedBy from Class__History`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on sfdcfox's answer, if you want the person who made the last change to a field `foo__c` on some sobject instance:

```
select createdById, oldvalue, newvalue 
      from Class__History 
      where field = 'foo__c` and 
            parentId = :someParentId
      order by createdDate desc 
      limit 1
```

Comment: Nice Trick..Thanks to all especially to sfdcfox as he shared the technical reason behind this. Sfdcbox,one thing i would like to request could you please share the source where you have read this.I m really impressed by the word immutable,next time if i anyone ask me i can support myself with same technical reasons too.

Answer (score 2):

Field history is immutable, and therefore does not have either LastModifiedById or LastModifiedDate. LastModifiedById and LastModifiedDate are equal to CreatedById and CreatedDate, respectively.

In the documentation for [System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm), the documentation states:

> Not all standard objects have all audit fields. Check the Enterprise WSDL to verify which audit fields are available for a given object.

Generally speaking, if you can't call `update` on an object, there are no LastModifiedById or LastModifiedDate fields. Read the [Standard Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) documentation to find an object; if the "Supported Operations" section does not include "update", the Last Modified audit fields will generally not exist.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox,Please share the source where can we read all the technical reasons behind the behaviors or apex.Is it in Apex documentation.It will increase the knowledge of everyone.

Comment: @ArunSharma There's no very specific list of objects/fields that are different, but I did find a bit of a note stating that not all audit fields are on all objects.

Comment: @ArunSharma And "immutable" simply means "cannot be modified." It's a very generic programming term that you'll see in many languages, such as Java.